Significance of simultaneous transformation of $t$ and $\phi$ in kerr metric
The Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinate is invariant under simultaneous transformations $t \rightarrow -t$ and $\phi \rightarrow -\phi$ but not invariant if we apply one transformation only. What is the significance of it? Like how do we describe such behavior of Kerr metric in terms of physics or astrophysics?

Sounds like a homework exercise.

it is not a homework exercise. I am writing a review on Kerr Black holes and I am not sure what reasons should I give for such behavior
